# Compile time detection of functions that should not throw but still do (noexcept or alternative ways)

Tags: c++, exception

I am aware that [noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) is merely informative and gcc/clang do not trigger any warnings/errors with this snippet:

```
void foo() noexcept
{
  throw 1;
}

int main()
{
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

So - is there a way or technique to mark a function to not throw anything and actually get a compile time warning/error from the compiler if the implementation does throw?

A simple use case - I have a framework that exposes a set of interfaces that client plugins should implement, the framework then loads the plugins from shared objects, instantiates the interfaces through factories and calls the interface methods. I would prefer that no exceptions are thrown over the library boundaries during the call so I want to mark all the functions in interfaces implemented by the plugins to not throw instead of relying on the implementation having a `try`/`catch` block inside. Are there any common techniques/alternative solutions for this?

I also understand that no compile time checks can detect potential structured exceptions that can occur during runtime because of invalid data but is there anything that works for at least C++ exceptions?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the comment by Jason I checked what was happening with function pointers and was also let down a bit - clang at least complains on the snippet below, gcc does not:

```
void foo() noexcept
{
  throw 1;
}

void bar() noexcept(false)
{
}

int main()
{
  void (*safe_function_one)() noexcept  = &foo;  
  void (*safe_function_two)() noexcept  = &bar;  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61372) might be related.

Comment: @Caninonos great find, this is towards the direction I was looking for, thanks:)

Comment: Keep in mind, functions can be bound at runtime so the compiler can't *guarantee* `noexcept` at compile time.

Comment: @Jason - well this was a bit of a letdown for me, I just found that you can't use `noexcept` in function pointer definitions to at least check that the pointers are compatbile. At least clang complains, gcc does not.

Comment: There was actually some heavy debate on Scott Meyers' [suggestion](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/03/declare-functions-noexcept-whenever.html) to *use `noexcept` whenever possible* since it could be a false guarantee.  I only use it on functions I personally *know* will not throw.  Adding it to an interface can't enforce implementers don't throw exceptions though, so depending on the situation (e.g. function pointers), it might not be a safe thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that noexcept is a clue to the compiler that it does not need provide mechanisms to properly unroll the stack frame in this particular function (to protect from an exception), allowing it to optimize a bit more.  If an exception is thrown anyway, proper recovery may not be possible.

**std::move_if_noexcept** is the key to the purpose of noexcept.  noexcept was needed for a specific situation with move semantics, which is described [here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2855.html#problem).

And like you point out, invalid data would be impossible to determine at compile time.  And while detecting 'throw' in the root scope of the function would be trivial, analyzing all possible code paths that may be called from that function to determine if an exception is thrown is a bit more work.  I suspect all compilers have this on their list, and are working toward a solution, however noexcept was never meant to be a guarantee, so I suspect this is debated with a fair amount of passion.

For now, you may want to decorate the funtions with noexcept, and allow the compiler to generate faster code, and communicate very strongly that throwing exceptions will produce unstable behavior.  However the compiler can perform some of these optimizations anyway, even without noexcept.  For instance, the compiler can easily determine many inline functions are good candidates.

**EDIT:**
As @Creris correctly points out, std::terminate() will be called immediately if a matching exception handler cannot be located (which is very undesirable), but this certainly doesn't stop a developer from using throw in these situations.

Comment: Yeah, I already stated in the question that I was aware that a full detection during compile time is impossible and that `noexcept` is more of a decoration. I was just hoping that anyone will turn up with a mythical gcc or clang switch that at least produces warnings:)

Comment: "If a search for a matching exception handler leaves a function marked noexcept or noexcept(true), std::terminate is called immediately." from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec so no, there is no way to throw from noexcept function

Comment: @Creris ok I clarified the title, the question is about compile time detection not runtime consequences. Thanks for the comment, I thought I expressed the intent clearly enough but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: @Creris, you are right that std::terminate() will get called if a throw is not caught, it certainly doesn't stop a throw from being used.  Try it.

Comment: @nullptr, thanks for the link on move constructors, that was interesting, +1 from me